# How to resolve mqtt broker issue: Connection Refused: unacceptable protocol version.?

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a a group of docker containers which I start from a docker-compose file.They communicate with each other via an MQTT Broker. This all works good. I have this set of containers deployed to an Ubuntu enviornment and I want to use the MQTTX CLI tool so I can publish and subbscribe from an Ubuntu terminal.
Here is where the problem comes, I have installed MQTTX CLI at the Ubuntu and I try to subcribe and publish but connection is refused because of my protocol version of mqtt being unacceptable.

This is my broker version:

[image]

As I have said, it works fine, services are able to communicate well but I cannot subscribe or publish to the topics because of that issue which I am not sure how to resolve. I tried
adding 'bridge_protocol_version mqttv311' to the mosquitto config file but that did not help.

Comment: Are you sure that's the broker version that is actually being used (1.4.12 is **VERY** old, you should be using something a lot newer) and not a broker in a container started by the compose manifest? Also have you looked at the broker logs to see what version the tool you are using is sending? Thirdly have you looked at what configuration options mqttx has and what defaults it uses?

Answer (score 2):

The MQTT X [documentation](https://github.com/emqx/MQTTX/tree/main/cli#usage) clearly states that it defaults to MQTT v5

> ```
> Options                           Description
> -V, --mqtt-version <5/3.1.1/3.1>  the MQTT version (default: 5)
> -h, --hostname                    the broker host (default: "localhost")
> -p, --port                        the broker port
> -i, --client-id                   the client id
> --no-clean                        set the clean session flag to false (default: true)
> -k, --keepalive                   send a ping every SEC seconds (default: 30)
> ```

As Version 5 of the MQTT [spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html) was not ratified until March 2019, the version of your MQTT broker is from 2017 it can't possibly support v5 (that and the help output lists the supported version 3.1.1 & 3.1).